# Having a script look for records once every February 1st yearly

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to think of a way (I am pretty new to sql) to get this script to only look for records once every year on February 1st. Any help would be awesome.

```
select permit.PERMITID, SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT.permitrequested, PERMITSTATUS.NAME
from PERMIT
inner join SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT
on permit.PERMITID = SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT.ID
inner join PERMITSTATUS
on permitstatus.PERMITSTATUSID = permit.PERMITSTATUSID
where Typeofpermitrequested = 'GUID' AND permit.PERMITSTATUSID = 'GUID'
AND PERMITTYPEID = 'GUID' AND getdate() = 2022-02-01
```

I am stuck at the date portion and how to have the script look each year incrementally until turned off. This is for yearly reports.

Comment: This looks like MS SQL Server. If so, consider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version. If SQL Server then Agent is not available in Express afaik.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you would need to amend your query to the following:

```
IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 2 -- Check if today's month is February
    AND DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) = 1 -- Check if today is the first of the month
BEGIN
    -- If it's the first of February, then return the query results

    select permit.PERMITID, SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT.permitrequested, PERMITSTATUS.NAME
    from PERMIT
    inner join SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT
    on permit.PERMITID = SAVERPERMITMANAGEMENT.ID
    inner join PERMITSTATUS
    on permitstatus.PERMITSTATUSID = permit.PERMITSTATUSID
    where Typeofpermitrequested = 'GUID' AND permit.PERMITSTATUSID = 'GUID'
    AND PERMITTYPEID = 'GUID';

END
```

However, you'd need to run that query every day & you'd get an empty result every day except February 1st.

So, a better option would be to employ something like [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent): create a job containing the above SELECT query & schedule it to run every year on February 1st.